# Adding a new record in Django Admin gives persistent error

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm just starting to mess around with Django. I created a new project and a new app. In that app I created a model and activated the admin. This seemed to work fine. I then wanted to add a couple new records to the database using the admin. In the first three tables this went fine, but in the fourth one (called '*locations*') I get this error saying: *'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'*. The full error is here on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/WjZat6NN

The strange thing is that when I now go back to the general admin page and want to click the table on which I just got the error, I get the error as well (so without trying to add anything).

My question: why is this happening? Maybe there is something wrong with my models.py, so I pasted it below this message as well.

All tips are welcome!

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class countries(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.country

class organisationTypes(models.Model):
    organisationType = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.organisationType

class organisations(models.Model):
    organisationName = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    organisationType = models.ForeignKey(organisationTypes)
    countryofOrigin = models.ForeignKey(countries)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.organisationName

class locations(models.Model):
    organisation = models.ForeignKey(organisations)
    countryofLocation = models.ForeignKey(countries)
    telNr = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.organisation, self.countryofLocation, self.telNr, self.address
```

Comment: just a note. You should follow the standard naming conventions. Class names capitalized like in most languages and class attributes and variables with words split by underscores ('_'). Not with camelcase which is what you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
def __unicode__(self):
        return self.organisation, self.countryofLocation, self.telNr, self.address
```

You're returning a tuple. It expects a single string.

Change it to something like this:

```
def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s - %s - %s - %s" % (self.organisation self.countryofLocation, self.telNr, self.address)
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is most likely with this line...

```
return self.organisation, self.countryofLocation, self.telNr, self.address
```

...where you're returning a tuple from a `__unicode__` method. You'll need to return a string object instead, although it's unclear what it should be. Perhaps...

```
return ', '.join((self.organisation, self.countryofLocation, self.telNr, self.address))
```

...?

Answer (score 1):

You can only return  a string to acts as a representative to a model instance.

So better use

```
return self.organisation + '-'+ self.countryofLocation + '-'+self.telNr+'-'+self.address
```